# Custom blurred pointiness node using normal input

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, procedural

[image]

I need to create blurred curvature map, I'm currently using *Pointiness* input along with *ColorRamp* node but because the *Pointiness* node doesn't depend on coordinates input I'm unable to blur the result by distorting the input coordinates using noise texture.

I'm assuming that all the geometry info I need to replicate the same effect are available in the normal input coordinates yet I do not know exactly how to process it.

[image]

So I used this formula to calculate the angle between two adjacent vectors (see the attached file) but it's not even close. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: Not sure to get the result you want to have. But what if you mix the pointiness after it is changed by two color ramps?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? not quite understanding what you're alluding to

Comment: meant mixing 2 color ramps which have pointiness as input, instead of "extending" input coordinates.But still hard to figure out what the result you're looking for exactly.